# How do add a new user to Hue/Hive with permissions?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I have a Hadoop cluster that I manage via the Hue interface to run Hive queries.

I would like to add another user to Hue and give them access to SOME of the table to run queries on. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think Hive has those kinds of security features? The user could just go and look in HDFS for the data anyway.

Comment: That ok, because they won't have an SSH login to the machine. Only to the Hue interface.

Answer (score 0):

Hue is just a view on top of Hive so using [Hive Authorization](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-auth.html) should do it (beware: Hive Authorization is currently being reworked in order to be really secure).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add that user to the hadoop group that you must have created to run hadoop. Also you might want to create a separate working directory for each user on hadoop.